# New to C -- am I doing something unsafe here?

Tags: c

I want to write a function that cycles an array created with malloc while adding a new element to the back. Here is the code:

```
int * cycle_and_append(int *arr, int size, int newvalue) {

    int * newarr = (int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    newarr = & arr[1];
    newarr[size-1] = newvalue;

    return newarr;
}
```

This compiles in GCC and behaves as I expected. For example:

```
int *test = (int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));
test[0] = 1;
test[1] = 2;
test[2] = 3;
//code to print contents of test goes here
test = cycle_and_append(test, 3, 42);
//print test again
```

The output from the first print is
1 2 3
and the output from the second is
2 3 42.

So it works, but looking at the code makes me feel like I'm doing something unsafe. Am I right to be wary or is this good to go?

Comment: Where do you free the allocated memory?

Comment: Totally unsafe -- the code results in a buffer overrun. The correct solution is to use `memmove` to move the existing elements of the array by 1. Then put the new value at the end of the array.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `realloc` instead of `malloc`, and then all the data would get copied over to the new memory area if the old memory area couldn't be extended.

Comment: @bruceg The array size stays the same. The first element is discarded, the remaining elements move one position to the left, and the new element is put at the end. That's why `1 2 3` becomes `2 3 42`

Comment: @user3386109 weird. I wonder why the OP needs to allocate a new buffer?

Comment: @Dweeberly I don't free it because I'm a C noob. Fortunately I haven't actually stuck this into my code because I was afraid it was wrong (as it was indeed).

Comment: @bruceg I didn't actually need to allocate a new buffer--as I explained below, I was just hoping to cheat and modify the array without actually touching every element. Needless to say I don't intend to keep this code now that I know how much is wrong with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for asking--unfortunately this is unsafe. The line, `newarr = & arr[1];` discards the array you allocated in the line above, and makes `newarr` point into the existing array (which is too small to hold the new value for certain value of `size`). Additionally, you leak memory since you don't pair mallocs with frees.

In your case, you probably got lucky since you didn't run into off-limits memory or overwrite something important. With larger arrays or more calls, you could end up crashing (and bugs of this type can also lead to security flaws).

Assuming that you can clobber the input rather than copying, you can [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) the array and shift the elements around; alternatively you can construct the new array and copy into it. Note that I assume that `size` is at most the size of the old array plus one:

```
int * cycle_and_append(int *arr, int size, int newvalue) {

    int * newarr = (int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < (size-1); i++) {
        newarr[i] = arr[i+1]
    }
    newarr[size-1] = newvalue;
    // either free(arr) or put that responsibility onto the caller
    return newarr;
}
```

To improve this further you could tweak the meaning of `size` to better reflect that it's the size of the old array:

```
int * cycle_and_append(int *arr, int oldsize, int newvalue) {

    int * newarr = (int *) malloc((oldsize+1)*sizeof(int));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < oldsize; i++) {
        newarr[i] = arr[i+1]
    }
    newarr[oldsize] = newvalue;

    // either free(arr) or put that responsibility onto the caller
    return newarr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure where ```free``` should go because I was confused about the memory I was allocating with malloc. I only half understood I was discarding the old array with ```newarr = & arr[1];```. My intention was for size to be the same as the old array's size, and to try to cheat the whole process of copying the array element by element. Can I ask what you mean by "clobber the input"?

Comment: @thersites Clobbering the input means that the input array is no longer usable. It becomes important if you need to keep the array both before and after the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is very unsafe!

```cpp
int * cycle_and_append(int *arr, int size, int newvalue) {

    /* here we allocate some new memory */
    int * newarr = (int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    /* 
      now now have a memory leak since you are overwriting
      the previously returned address of newarr. We can no
      longer free the memory
    */
    newarr = & arr[1];

    /* if previously we had 3 elements in the array,
       you have shortened the array by 1 (via &arr[1]),
       and are writing beyond the end of the array. 
       This is not good! 
    */
    newarr[size-1] = newvalue;

    return newarr;
}
```

It all you are attempting to do is move the elements down one, and write a new value to the end of the array, you probably don't need to be allocating a new array each time.

```cpp
void cycle_and_append(int *arr, int size, int newvalue) {
  for(int i = 1; i < size; ++i) 
  {
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
  }
  arr[size - 1] = newvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `malloc` line, you define a new array of size `size`; that should be `(size + 1)`, for you're adding a new integer...

But a major mistake is one line after: your code loses the pointer pointing to that array. Arrays don't work that way. After creating allocated memory;

(1) you need to copy the old array to the new one (starting from index 0),

(2) then, add the new element at the end.

```
int *cycle_and_append(int *arr, int size, int newvalue) {
    int *newarr = (int *) malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // if the new element is to be added at the end
        *(newarr + i) = *(arr + i);
        // if the new element is to be added at the beginning
        *(newarr + i + 1) = *(arr + i);
    }

    // if the new element is to be added at the end
    newarr[size] = newvalue;
    // if the new element is to be added at the beginning
    newarr[0] = newvalue;

    return newarr;
}
```